# Can't perform crud operation on API data stored in SQLite DB Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqflite

I am learning Flutter and have recently worked with JSON placeholder APIs and performed CRUD operations. But now I am trying to store the API data in local DB SQLite and perform CRUD operations in SQLite DB locally. And facing issues related to CRUD or state management (I am not sure). When I am performing CRUD, the state is changing accordingly but when I close the app and try to view the updated data then I see the previous data. Or sometimes a white screen when I press the delete button. I am really trying to find out the exact problem and its solution but can't find one. Maybe it's a minor problem. But please help me to solve this. This will help others also who are new like me.

Here is my code:

HomeScreen:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:offline_storage/api_to_sqflite.dart';
import 'package:offline_storage/data_card.dart';
import 'package:offline_storage/database.dart';
import 'package:offline_storage/posts_model.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({super.key});

@override
State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
late ConnectivityResult result;
late StreamSubscription subscription;
var isConnected = false;

TextEditingController userIdController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController bodyController = TextEditingController();

List<PostsModel> posts = [];
late DatabaseHelper _database;
bool fetching = true;

int currentIndex = 0;

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
_database = DatabaseHelper.instance;
super.initState();
getPost();
_fromApi();
debugPrint("init properly working.........");
}

_fromApi() {
_loadFromApi();
getPost();
debugPrint("Working....");
}

_loadFromApi() async {
debugPrint("Load from Api Working.....");
await Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then(
  (value) => showsnackbar(
    context,
    "Api Data Downloaded.",
  ),
);
var apiProvider = ApiToSqflite();
await apiProvider.fetchDataAndStoreInSQLite();
}

void getPost() async {
debugPrint("Get Post Working.....");
posts = await _database.getPost();
setState(() {
  fetching = false;
});
}

checkInternet() async {
result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
if (result != ConnectivityResult.none) {
  isConnected = true;
} else {
  isConnected = false;
  showNetDialog();
}
setState(() {});
}

showNetDialog() {
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: const Text("NO internet"),
    content: const Text("Please check your internet connection"),
    actions: [
      TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          checkInternet();
        },
        child: const Text(
          "Retry",
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
 );
}

startStreaming() {
subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((event) async {
  checkInternet();
});
}

void _showDialog() {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text("Do you really want to download the api data ?"),
        content: const Text(
            "All the previous changes on API data will be deleted."),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              startStreaming();
              _fromApi();
              Navigator.pop(context);
              // if (!mounted) return;
            },
            child: const Text('Yes'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('No'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
 }

void showsnackbar(BuildContext context, String text) {
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Text(text),
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
);
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: const Text('Offline Storage'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
        child: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_input_antenna),
          onPressed: () async {
            _showDialog();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showMyDialogue();
    },
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
  body: fetching
      ? const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => DataCard(
            posts: posts[index],
            edit: edit,
            index: index,
            delete: delete,
          ),
        ),
  // Center(child: Text(posts[100].title)),
 );
}

void showMyDialogue() async {
return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: AlertDialog(
            content: Container(
              height: 320,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: userIdController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "user id",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ],
                    maxLines: 1,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: titleController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "title",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    maxLines: 3,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: bodyController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "body",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    maxLines: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    PostsModel postsLocal = PostsModel(
                      userId: int.parse(userIdController.text),
                      title: titleController.text,
                      body: bodyController.text,
                    );
                    _database.insertPost(postsLocal);
                    postsLocal.id = posts[posts.length - 1].id! + 1;
                    setState(() {
                      posts.add(postsLocal);
                    });
                    userIdController.clear();
                    titleController.clear();
                    bodyController.clear();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    debugPrint("Save button pressed");
                  },
                  child: const Text("Save"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
 }

void showMyDialogueUpdate() async {
return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: AlertDialog(
            content: Container(
              height: 320,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: userIdController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "user id",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: titleController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "title",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    maxLines: 3,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: bodyController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "body",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    maxLines: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    PostsModel updatedPost = posts[currentIndex];
                    updatedPost.userId = int.parse(userIdController.text);
                    updatedPost.title = titleController.text;
                    updatedPost.body = bodyController.text;
                    _database.updatePost(updatedPost, updatedPost.id!);
                    // _database.getPost();
                    setState(() {
                      // _database.getPost();
                    });
                    userIdController.clear();
                    titleController.clear();
                    bodyController.clear();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    debugPrint("Update button pressed");
                  },
                  child: const Text("Update"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
 }

void edit(index) {
currentIndex = index;
userIdController.text = posts[index].userId.toString();
titleController.text = posts[index].title;
bodyController.text = posts[index].body;

showMyDialogueUpdate();
setState(() {});
debugPrint(fetching.toString());
}

void delete(index) {
_database.deletePost(posts[index].id!);
posts.removeAt(index);
debugPrint(fetching.toString());
debugPrint("Data Deleted");
setState(() {});
debugPrint(fetching.toString());
}
}
```

Data Card:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:offline_storage/posts_model.dart';

class DataCard extends StatelessWidget {
const DataCard({
super.key,
required this.posts,
required this.edit,
required this.delete,
required this.index,
});
final PostsModel posts;
final Function edit;
final Function delete;

final int index;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.lightGreen[100],
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            const TextSpan(
              text: 'Post Id: ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: posts.id.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            const TextSpan(
              text: 'User Id: ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: posts.userId.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            const TextSpan(
              text: 'Title: ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: posts.title.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            const TextSpan(
              text: 'Body: ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: posts.body.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              debugPrint('trying to update');
              edit(index);
            },
            child: const Text('Update'),
          ),
          // SizedBox(
          //   width: ,
          // ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              delete(index);
            },
            child: const Text('Delete'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Post Model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<PostsModel> employeeFromJson(String str) =>
List<PostsModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => PostsModel.fromJson(x)));

String employeeToJson(List<PostsModel> data) =>
json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class PostsModel {
int userId;
int? id;
String title;
String body;

PostsModel({
required this.userId,
this.id,
required this.title,
required this.body,
});

// to get data from database (JSON to object)
factory PostsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostsModel(
    userId: json['userId'],
    id: json['id'],
    title: json['title'],
    body: json['body'],
  );
// to store data in database (object to JSON)
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "userId": userId,
    "id": id,
    "title": title,
    "body": body,
  };
}
```

API to SQLITE:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'posts_model.dart';
import 'database.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiToSqflite {
Future<List<PostsModel>?> fetchDataAndStoreInSQLite() async {
// Fetch data from API
var response =
    await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
// List<dynamic> jsonList = jsonDecode(response.body);
var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  for (Map<String, dynamic> index in data) {
    debugPrint("Fahad.....");
    DatabaseHelper.instance.insertPost(PostsModel.fromJson(index));
    // postsList.add(PostsModel.fromJson(index));
  }
  debugPrint('Data fetched from API and stored in SQLite successfully!');
  return data;
} else {
  debugPrint('Failed to fetch data from API');
  throw Exception('Failed to fetch notes');
  // return null;
}
}
}
```

Database:

```
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names, avoid_init_to_null

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'posts_model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
static Database? _db = null;

static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._instance();

DatabaseHelper._instance();

static const String postTable = 'postTable';
static const String userId = 'userId';
static const String id = 'id';
static const String title = 'title';
static const String body = 'body';
static const String dbName = 'posts.db';

/*
This is how the posts table will look
id / userId / title / body 
0     --      --      --
1     --      --      --
2     --      --      --
*/

Future<Database?> get db async {
_db ??= await _initDb();
return _db;
}

Future<Database?> _initDb() async {
Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
debugPrint('Database Location: ${dir.path}');
// final path = '${dir.path}posts.db';
final path = join(dir.path, 'posts.db');
final db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
return db;
}

void _createDb(Database db, int version) async {
await db.execute("""
  CREATE TABLE $postTable(
    $id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    $userId INTEGER,
    $title TEXT,
    $body TEXT)
  """);
}

// INSERT
Future<int> insertPost(PostsModel posts) async {
Database? db = await this.db;
final int result = await db!.insert(
  postTable,
  posts.toJson(),
  conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
);
return result;
}

// READ
Future<List<PostsModel>> getPost() async {
final db = await this.db;
final result = await db?.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $postTable");

List<PostsModel> posts = result!.isNotEmpty
    ? result.map((c) => PostsModel.fromJson(c)).toList()
    : [];

return posts;
}

// UPDATE
Future<int> updatePost(PostsModel posts, int id) async {
Database? db = await this.db;
final int result = await db!.update(
  postTable,
  posts.toJson(),
  where: '$id = ?',
  whereArgs: [id],
);
return result;
}

// DELETE
Future<int> deletePost(int id) async {
Database? db = await this.db;
final int result = await db!.delete(
  postTable,
  where: '$id = ?',
  whereArgs: [id],
);
return result;
}

// DROP THE TABLE
Future<int> dropTable() async {
Database? db = await this.db;
return await db!.rawDelete('DELETE FROM postTable');
}

// CLOSE THE DATABASE
Future close() async {
Database? db = await this.db;
db!.close();
}
}
```

This is the code of my project. Please Help.